# как подключить внешнюю базу данных SQLite с данными в Android Studio проект с языком программирования Kotlin

Tags: android, sqlite, kotlin

хочу написать офлайн словарь у меня есть .db файл с "_id, word, description", хочу подключить эту базу данных в Котлин проект для считывания данных оттуда. В интернете очень мало туториалов на Котлин, уже третий день пытаюсь разными способами выполнить задачу, но без успеха. Нашел туториал где все вроде именно так как я хотел, строка с AutoCompleteTextView, куда вводишь слово для поиска и считывая с базы выдает слово. Удалось даже cкопировать .db в 'data/data/"projectname"/database' но дальше считывать не получается, в этом этапе просто нужно чтобы при поиске на **AutoCompleteTextView** выводились слова со столбца **word**.
Проект состоит из 3 файлов: **MainActivity.kt**, **DbHelper.kt**, **activity_main.xml**

**MainActivity.kt**

```
package com.fabrikam.dictionary

import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.text.Editable
import android.text.TextWatcher
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter
import android.widget.AutoCompleteTextView



class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {


    lateinit var dbHelper: DbHelper
    lateinit var searchv: AutoCompleteTextView

    var sugList = ArrayList<String>()

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        dbHelper = DbHelper(this, "database.db", 1)
        dbHelper.checkDb()


        searchv.findViewById<AutoCompleteTextView>(R.id.idSearchView)
        var adapter = ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,  sugList)



        searchv.addTextChangedListener(object: TextWatcher{



            override fun afterTextChanged(p0: Editable?) {

            }

            override fun beforeTextChanged(p0: CharSequence?, p1: Int, p2: Int, p3: Int) {

            }

            override fun onTextChanged(p0: CharSequence?, p1: Int, p2: Int, p3: Int) {
               sugList.addAll(dbHelper.searchSugg(p0.toString()))
                searchv.setAdapter(adapter)
            }

            })
        }

    }
```

**DbHelper.kt**

```
package com.fabrikam.dictionary

import android.content.Context
import android.database.Cursor
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper
import android.util.Log
import java.io.FileOutputStream

class DbHelper (context:Context, name: String, version: Int): SQLiteOpenHelper(context, name, null, version){

    var mcontext: Context
    var dbName: String
    var dbPath: String

    init {
        mcontext = context
        dbName = name
        dbPath = "/data/data" + "com.fabrikam.dictionary" + "/databases/"
    }


    override fun onCreate(p0: SQLiteDatabase?) {
        //TODO("Not yet implemented")
    }

    override fun onUpgrade(p0: SQLiteDatabase?, p1: Int, p2: Int) {
        // TODO("Not yet implemented")
    }

    fun checkDb (){
        try {
            var filePath = mcontext.getDatabasePath(dbName)
            if (!filePath.exists()) copyDatabase()
            else  Log.d("Copydb", "db already available")
        } catch (e: Exception){
            e.stackTrace
        }
    }

    fun copyDatabase(){
        this.readableDatabase
        Log.d("Copydb", "Creating a new copy from a asset fonder")


        try {
            var ios = mcontext.assets.open(dbName)
            var os = FileOutputStream(dbPath +dbName)

            var buffer = ByteArray(1024)
            var len = ios.read(buffer)

            while ((len)> 0){
                os.write(buffer, 0, len)
                len = ios.read(buffer)

            }

            ios.close()
            os.close()
            os.flush()
        } catch (e: java.lang.Exception){
            e.stackTrace
        }
        Log.d("Copydb", "db copied")
    }


    fun searchSugg(query: String): ArrayList<String>{

        var tableName = "content"
        var colName = "word"

        var list = ArrayList<String>()
        var db  = this.readableDatabase

        var cursor: Cursor = db.query(
            tableName,
            arrayOf(colName),
            colName + "LIKE ?",
            arrayOf(query + "%"),
            null, null,
            colName
        )

        var index = cursor.getColumnIndex(colName)
        while (cursor.moveToNext()){
            list.add(cursor.getString(index))
        }

        return list
    }

}
```

**activity_main**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView

        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Enter your word"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:textSize="30dp"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
         />


    <AutoCompleteTextView
        android:id="@+id/idSearchView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:hint="Here..."/>
</LinearLayout>
```

и скрин от **database.db**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

ошибка которая выдает, *lateinit property searchv has not been initialized*, то есть searchv не принимает данные с .db. Можно программу запустить переделав *lateinit* на *var searchv: AutoCompleteTextView? =null*, но и тогда при поиске ничего не выдает. Буду благодарен за помощь.

```
D/Copydb: db already available
D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.fabrikam.dictionary, PID: 9161
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.fabrikam.dictionary/com.fabrikam.dictionary.MainActivity}: kotlin.UninitializedPropertyAccessException: lateinit property searchv has not been initialized
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2778)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2856)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1589)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
     Caused by: kotlin.UninitializedPropertyAccessException: lateinit property searchv has not been initialized
        at com.fabrikam.dictionary.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.kt:29)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7009)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7000)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1214)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2731)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2856) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1589) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
```

Comment: Ваша задача никак не связана с вашей ошибкой. Вы просто неправильно инициализируете переменную. Замените `searchv.findViewById<AutoCompleteTextView>(R.id.idSearchView)` на `searchv = findViewById<AutoCompleteTextView>(R.id.idSearchView)`

Comment: Спасибо огромное, вам за помощь, проблема с инициализацией решилось, но другая проблема возникла

`E/SQLiteLog: (1) no such table: content`
`D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM`
`E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main Process: com.fabrikam.dictionary, PID: 12443`
  `android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: content (code 1):` , while compiling: SELECT word FROM content WHERE word LIKE ? ORDER BY word  **

Comment: @ЮрийСПб Удалил программу из AVD заново установил, не помогло. Также поменял `dbHelper = DbHelper(this, "database.db", 2)` версию дб на 2, тогда выдал ошибку `java.lang.IllegalStateException: getDatabase called recursively`

Comment: Это уже отдельная проблема. Задайте отдельный вопрос. Судя по логу у вас нужной таблицы в БД нет